# How to undo an update of Galaxy S7 edge?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

My Galaxy S7 edge has been rebooted automatically. So I installed the last update suggested in my settings (that I was ignoring for almost 2 weeks). Now I'm not able to use many feathers, as the left touch button that shows opened apps, and I can't recieve notifications even if I hear the sound of it. Also, my personal settings has been reset.

Is there any way to fix that **without** flashing it or applying Factory Data Reset since I have plenty of apps and accounts that I want to keep.

Specifications:
**Galaxy S7 edge |
Marshmalow 6.0.1 |
Official ROM**

Thank you!

Comment: What is *many feathers*? An app? Also: A factory reset will *not* undo updates, it will only delete user data.

Comment: Issues I've detected:
- No more notifications, just sounds
- Can't modify my wifi, bluethoot,.. toggles.
- All personal settings are reseted.

Now I have Marshmallow 6.0.1 and an Official ROM